# Deserialize ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, serialization

I have my own little serialiser class

```
package mypackage.shared;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class Serializer {

    static final String HEXES = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    public static String serialize(Object o) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(stream);

        os.writeObject(o);
        os.close();
        return toHex(stream.toByteArray());
    }

    public static Object deserialize(String hexString)  throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        byte[] serializedBytes = toByteArray(hexString);
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(serializedBytes);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis); 

        Object o = null;
        o = ois.readObject();
        ois.close(); 
        return o;
    }

    public static String toHex( byte [] raw ) {
        if ( raw == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        final StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder( 2 * raw.length );
        for ( final byte b : raw ) {
            hex.append(HEXES.charAt((b & 0xF0) >> 4))
            .append(HEXES.charAt((b & 0x0F)));
        }
        return hex.toString();
    }

    private static byte[] toByteArray(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                    + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }

}
```

It works great for some home made objects I have. However, as soon as I have an ArrayList of these objects it fails to deserialize them. ANy idea why that would be? I find it quite hard to debug since readObject() just fails

Comment: Does this only work for your *home-made* objects, or regular java objects like `String` etc? Does it only fail for `List`s of your objects, or does it also fail for `List<Integer>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If serialization doesn't work it means that some object is not serializable.

Try to deserialize an arraylist containing only one home object and do it for all home objects